# Python - How do i remove the window border? I have imported UI from Qt into Python and applied setWindowFlags

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt4, fedora

How to make this window Border-less (remove minimize/maximize/close)?

[image]

```
  1 import sys
  2 from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
  3 from qt import Ui_MainWindow
  4 
  5 class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  6     def __init__(self, parent=None):
  7         QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
  8         self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  9         self.ui.setupUi(self))
 10         
 11 if __name__ == "__main__":
 12     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
 13     myapp = StartQT4()
 14     myapp.show()
 15     app.setWindowFlags(app.FramelessWindowHint) <<< does not working
 16     sys.exit(app.exec_())
 17
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the window flag before calling `show` on the main window.

A minimal working example would look like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartQT4, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.b = QtGui.QPushButton("exit", self, clicked=self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = StartQT4()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4):

Some windowflags need to be set in the constructor to `QMainWindow`, I suspect this is one. See the [documentation for QMainWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#QMainWindow) for more info.

Note that your `STartQT4.__init__` calls the wrong constructor. You should call `QMainWindow.__init__`, not `QWidget.__init__`.

Use `super(StartQT4,self).__init__(parent, <windowflags>)` instead