# PyQt - Widget in QtGui.QtMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a window(QtGui.QMainWindow) that I'm trying to add text, but I know you can't add text to a window in pyqt so im adding a widget into the window but the widget isnt showing up only the dialog

here is the window code:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
         self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
         self.setWindowOpacity(.9)
         text_widget = text(self)
         self.widgets = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
         self.widgets.addWidget(text_widget)
         self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { background: 'black'}");
```

and here is the widget I'm trying to add:

```
class text(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(text, self).__init__(parent)
         self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel('Welcome')
         layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
         layout.addWidget(self.label1)
         self.setLayout(layout)a
```

and if needed i can post the whole code that displays the dialog window that i want to show up with the main window. the main window is full screen with an opacity lowered as its I'm trying to add an background so you cant exit out of my log in screen the dialog displays a frameless window so it cant be moved around. and i want the dialog to be displayed along with the widget

here is the whole code for somebody that may need it for timesake as its quite long i just pasted it on bpaste http://bpaste.net/show/Xus3ME83YTjiEK4gnqRu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the widget to be the the central widget of your `MyWindow` MainWindow. QMainWindow should have a central widget set.

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowOpacity(.9)
        text_widget = text(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(text_widget)
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { background: 'black'}");
```

Or the stack widget, or whatever. But if you create a `QMainWindow` then you have to set it's central widget if you want it to appear.

**Update:**

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowOpacity(.9)
        text_widget = text(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(text_widget)
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { background: 'black'}");

class text(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(text, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel('Welcome', self)
        self.label1.move(100, 10)
        self.label1.setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : red; font-size: 28px; }")
```

Comment: still cant see it my dialog is in the middle of the screen do i have to move the widget?

Comment: Can you paste the whole code example that produces the problem? Since I don't see any dialog in the current example you provided.

Comment: 1 second have to get it of my pi

Comment: for timesake i just put it on a paste so here if you run it rember the password is password and the username is admin the only way to get out of it is by loging out of yourcomputer if you dont know the password http://bpaste.net/show/Xus3ME83YTjiEK4gnqRu/

Comment: OK, so I don't know what exactly are you trying to accomplish, but there are a few problems. First the dialog is over the text, because the text is centered, and the dialog is also centered. The second problem is that the color of the background is the same as the color of the text :D So you don't see it :)

Comment: If you remove the line with the styleSheet (the line 65) and you add a stretch `layout.addStretch()` (after line 71) you will see the text on the left side of the window.

Comment: is there a way i can change the color of the text and raise the text? im new to pyqt and trying to learn it. and if you want to know what im trying to acomplish look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261859/pyqt-how-do-i-fade-the-desktop-background-behind-a-dialog-similar-to-windows

Comment: To raise the text use the `VBoxLayout` in the `text` class and add stretch as I explained in the previous comment. The easiest way to change label text color is to set the text to `'<font color='red'>Some text</font>'`

Comment: could you update you code with some examples as this is kinda confusing with out an example

Comment: Updated. Just copy and paste those two classes.

Comment: is there a way i can input cordanates to the text?

Comment: i don't see where you can inset coordinates other than lbl1.move(#, #) but that doesn't work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35679/discussion-between-viktor-kerkez-and-raspberry-pi)

Comment: It works, just have to set the parent widget. Update the example.